# Rails record from AJAX post not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an HTML table that displays order items. On each table row I have a "Need By Date" field that is standalone(not in a form) input field. Whenever a user changes the date, I post this date to the server to save it against the order.

I am noticing that when I use OrderItem.update or OrderItem.update_attributes from the rails console it works, but when it is triggered from a field change event Rails does not trigger an update to the table.

```
#JavaScript
  $(".order-item.datepicker").change ->
    needby_date = $(this).val()
    order_item_url = $(this).data("order-item-url")
    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url: order_item_url
      data:
        needby_date: needby_date
```

My controller -

```
  def update_needby_date
    @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:order_item_id])
    @order_item.update_attribute(update_needby_date_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   { render :nothing => true }
    end
  end

  private

   def update_needby_date_params
     params.permit(:order_item_id, :needby_date)
   end
```

As you can see in the log file, the update is not being triggered -

```
Started POST "/order_items/1/update_needby_date" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-08 10:55:10 -0400
Processing by OrderItemsController#update_needby_date as */*
  Parameters: {"needby_date"=>"07/23/2014", "order_item_id"=>"1"}
  OrderItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: If you are using rails 4 then you need to permit your attributes else it won't save

Comment: I edited my question above to permit my attributes, but I get an error. Is that the correct format? ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: order_item_id):
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:68:in `update_needby_date'

Comment: Use it like this: `params.permit [:order_item_id, :needby_date]`, then    I guess you want update_attributes, not update_attribute

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Been at it for some time now, and this is driving me crazy with no error messages the update failing silently.